# How to fill all fields using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I use
page.type to fill a field using puppeteer.
If you have a multiple selector, then it will fill the first found field.

My goal is to fill all inputs that match the selector.
Ex : fill all textinput with class "red"

```
await page.type('input.red', 'your text here');
```

this will just fill the first input with red class and not fill other inputs with red class.

Comment: Please be clear and specific when you post your questions

Comment: await page.type('input.red', 'your text here');

Comment: Try writing a loop over all of the inputs. Please share a [mcve] of the code and site you're working with so others have enough context to offer a concrete solution.

Comment: await page.type('input.red', 'your text here');  that will fill the first one, not all inputs with red class. This is exactly what I try to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const elHandleArray = await page.$$('input[class="red"]') // Custom selector
for await (const item of elHandleArray) {
  await item.type('your text')
}
```

This will search all the elements that matches the params and type the text. You probably gonna need to filter the type of input, to difference text fields and radios/box.